# Pythonic way to add several identical values to a list

Tags: python, list

What is the most pythonic way to add several identical values to a list? Of course I can do it with loop or like

```
someList += [someValue for i in range(someNumber)]
```

But may be there is a better way or a function?

Comment: `someList.extend([3] * 10)` once the value is immutable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `someValue` is immutable, you can use multiplication:

```
someList += [someValue] * someNumber
```

This creates `someNumber` references to *the same `someValue` object*. This means that if `someValue` is a *mutable* object you'll see changes to that object reflected across all those references.

So for *mutable* types, you generally use a list comprehension to make sure a new object is created. To extend a list, instead of `+=` you could also use `list.extend()` with a generator expression:

```
someList.extend(['extra', 'list', 'elements'] for _ in range(someNumber))
```

Demo:

```
>>> someList = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> someList += ['spam'] * 5
>>> someList
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'spam', 'spam', 'spam', 'spam', 'spam']
```

and with a mutable object (a list in this case):

```
>>> someList = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> someList += [['spam']] * 5
>>> someList
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', ['spam'], ['spam'], ['spam'], ['spam'], ['spam']]
>>> someList[-1].append('ham')
>>> someList
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', ['spam', 'ham'], ['spam', 'ham'], ['spam', 'ham'], ['spam', 'ham'], ['spam', 'ham']]
>>> someList[-1] is someList[-2]
True
```

Answer (score 2):

try this if `somevalue` is immutable

```
someList += [somevalue] * somenum
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the `*` multiplicative operator, like so:

```
someList += [someValue] * someNumber
```

Note that this will make reference to the same element each time, and thus could produce undesired results if you are working with mutable types.

**Example:**

```
>>>someList = [5]
>>>someList += [10] * 10
>>>someList
[ 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to be referencing the same element each time (perhaps a mutable type, etc.), you can always use a list comprehension as you are doing to create new elements for each list item:

```
someList += [10 for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `repeat` function from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to make it clearer to the reader that what you are doing is repeating a value before adding it to a list:

```
import itertools as it
someList += it.repeat(someValue, someNumber)
```

Of course, I don't think your original code is unreadable or unpythonic to begin with...